# Back in a code while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I have a problem in a simple code with while loop. My problem is explained in code comments.

**CODE**

```
exit = False
    while not exit:
        choice = input("Test ")

        if choice== 1:
            print "hello"
            exit = False

        else:
            print "good morning"
            #I want to return to the first while with the input Test but I pass to the second while 
            exit = False


        exit1 = False
        while not exit1:
            choice = input("Test 1")

            if choice== 1:
                print "bye"
                exit1 = False

            else:
                print "good evening"
                #I want to return to the first while with the input Test but I return to the second while 
                exit = False
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: And how are you planning to exit the while loop ? as you are only assigning false to `exit and exit1` ? + you didn't mention whats your problem beside telling what you want in comments which is inconvenient...

Comment: what is this script supposed to do?

Comment: Just as a hint: The `continue` and `break` statements can be used to continue a loop with the next itteration or break it.

Comment: [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Answer (score 0):

I think what are you looking for are the `continue` and `break` statements.

The `continue` will interrupt the current iteration (and a new iteration is started, of course).

The `break` will interrupt the smallest enclosing loop.

Both statements work for `for` as well.

Take a look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) for some reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
outer = True

while outer:
    do_something
    if a:
        continue # will get you back to do_something
    if b:
        break # will end the outer loop
```

If you set `outer` to `False` somewhere, it will end the while loop in the next iteration.